# Closing JFrame with button click

Tags: java, swing

I have the jButton1 private member of JFrame and i wanted to close the frame when the button is clicked.

```
jButton1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
    }
});
```

I wanted to do `super.close()` but could not find close for super. Is there some way to refer to the JFrame

Answer (score 46):

You will need a reference to the specific frame you want to close but assuming you have the reference `dispose()` should close the frame.

```
jButton1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
       frameToClose.dispose();
    }
});
```

Comment: while this is true, you skip all EventListeners associated with the close event when you do it that way...

Comment: How to dispose this(current) JFrame???

Comment: What if I just want to close the frame but not kill the event?

Answer (score 18):

```
JButton b3 = new JButton("CLOSE");

b3.setBounds(50, 375, 250, 50);

b3.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        System.exit(0);
    }
});
```

Comment: Great for single window applications, but if you use this to close a single window, it will close all others as well...

Comment: @acp i want to close only same class not previous class in java swing

Comment: System.exit(0); method is working.. and also dispose(); method also good.

Comment: I don't think using System::exit is a good idea, since invoking System.exit() shuts down the whole JVM.

Answer (score 9):

It appears to me that you have two issues here. One is that JFrame does not have a `close` method, which has been addressed in the other answers.

The other is that you're having trouble referencing your JFrame. Within `actionPerformed`, `super` refers to ActionListener. To refer to the JFrame instance there, use `MyExtendedJFrame.super` instead (you should also be able to use `MyExtendedJFrame.this`, as I see no reason why you'd want to override the behaviour of `dispose` or `setVisible`).

Answer (score 4):

You can use super.dispose() method which is more similar to close operation.

Comment: thanks for trying to be helpful :-) Unfortunately, your answer doesn't add much useful, to the extent to being wrong (the listener's super has no dispose, no need to call the frame's super, see @lins314159 for complete details)

Answer (score 2):

You cat use `setVisible ()` method of JFrame (and set visibility to `false`) or `dispose ()` method which is more similar to `close` operation.

Comment: setVisible() method is not working for me. i also thought i can do close the application by doing set the visibility = false... i used System.out(0); method. it works.. dispose() method is also working.