# i want the window to close when the data has been inputed

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

i want the window to close as soon as the input has been typed and clicked on  add button.
also i would like a message to appear notifying the user that the input data has been saved.  at the moment this code is linked to a database object where it will store the input.

```
public class Add extends JFrame
             implements ActionListener {

/** {@link JTextField} where the user name is entered */
JTextField Inputusername = new JTextField(7);

/** {@link JTextField} where the user age is entered */
JTextField age = new JTextField(2);

/** {@link JTextField} where the user ID is entered */
JTextField inputuserid = new JTextField(4);

/** Add Client button */

JButton addnewclient = new JButton("Add Client");
/** male Jradiobutton */
JRadioButton male = new JRadioButton("Male");
/** female Jradiobutton */
JRadioButton female = new JRadioButton("Female");
/** label for the gender selection */
Label genders = new Label("please select gender of client");

/** call the database constructor*/

private Database db; 
public Add(Database db) 
    { this.db = db; 


    //allows the positioning 
    setLayout(new BorderLayout()); 

  //setting the size of the window
    setBounds(100, 100, 500, 200); 

 // the title of the window
    setTitle("add new Client"); 

    // dispose of the window when the close button is clicked
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

 // declared new panel  
    JPanel top = new JPanel(); 
    top.add(new JLabel("Enter username :"));
    top.add(Inputusername);
    top.add(new JLabel("Enter age:"));
    top.add(age);
    top.add(new JLabel("Enter userid:"));
    top.add(inputuserid);
    add("North",top);
    // declared new panel 
    JPanel bottom = new JPanel(); 
 // add the veritable of JButton to the top panel
    bottom.add(addnewclient); 
 // add the bottom panel to the bottom of the screen
    add("South",bottom); 

    JPanel middle = new JPanel();
    ButtonGroup bg = new ButtonGroup();
    bg.add(male);
    bg.add(female);
    middle.add(male);
    middle.add(female);
    add("Center",middle);

 // do not allow user to set the size of the screen
    setResizable(false);
 // make the program  visible
    setVisible(true);
 // listen to the button
   addnewclient.addActionListener(this);   
}  

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    String selection = "female"; 

    if (this.male.isSelected()) 
    {
         selection = "male"; 
    }

    User u = new User(Inputusername.getText(),  selection , age.getText(), inputuserid.getText());
    db.addUser(u);
```

}

Comment: I want a new computer... what's the question? Stack overflow isn't here to right your code for you

Comment: Nor is it here to *write* your code for you. ;-)

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels that's embarrassing... you could even say Stack overflow is actually here to 'right' your code as well...

Comment: @dann: yep, I can relate as I've made the same mistake a million times. Uh oh, looks like Simur is starting to shout. That'll make me want to help him.

Comment: i would like thank you all for you help i have managed to fix my issue with my application once again thank you very much

Answer (score 5):

Use [JOptionPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html#features), you have to look at [JOptionPane#showXxxDialog](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html#input), that could be returned desired workaround

Comment: thank you very much i got it to work with the  JOptionPane, my programe looks more professional.

Answer (score 5):

You can add some code to your action performed method. Have a look at the [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html) for JFrame for a list of methods, but what you probably want is call `this.dispose();`.

There are also some existing answers on stack overflow already such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2352727/closing-jframe-with-button-click).

EDIT: Be aware that this will dispose of the class you are using too; so if you still need some of the busy logic, then you want a method that hides the `JFrame` instead. I'm sure you can find this yourself, but it would be a better idea to separate out GUI from business logic.

Comment: dam.dev thank you very much I looked through the API, this is very important contains all the classes with explanations.  thanks alot

Comment: No worries, try to say exactly which part you are having trouble with next time, then people can offer better help sooner