# Which is the Java swing component to realize a window with a smaller X button?

Tags: java, swing, window, frame

Help me please to find which swing component should I use to display a window, similar to "Styles and Formatting" in Libre Office. It has a smaller "close" button and no icon at the left top. And, what is the most important for me, always remains in front of the main frame.

Such a window I would like to use in my Java application.

Thank you very much!

Comment: You're looking for a tool window, which I'm pretty sure doesn't exist entirely in Swing, you'd need to make most it yourself

Answer (score 0):

Seems you've not tried much... Just googling a bit you can find easily the 4 steps you need to achieve your goal:

- create a [`JFrame`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html),
- [put an <kbd>X</kbd> button in your `JFrame`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2352727/closing-jframe-with-button-click),
- [set a listener to <kbd>X</kbd> button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1234912/how-to-programmatically-close-a-jframe)
- [put `JFrame` on top](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14795995/how-can-i-set-a-jframe-to-be-always-on-top-and-focuse-enabled-until-it-is-closed)